# Change image for pushpin WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps, pushpin

I have 2 pushpins, pin1 and pin2.
How do I change the default black image to my own image? 
Please help. Thanks

Comment: What is WPF 7? And if it is WPF, why the Silverlight tag? And the image is also part of the Pushpin's `Content`, as answered before.

Answer (score 9):

You could use a `Image` and add it to a `MapLayer` if you don't necesserily need all pushpin functionality.

Example:

```
MapLayer mapLayer = new MapLayer();
Image myPushPin = new Image();
myPushPin.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("YOUR IMAGE URL",UriKind.Relative));
myPushPin.Width = 32; 
myPushPin.Height = 32;
mapLayer.AddChild(myPushPin, <LOCATION_OF_PIN>, PositionOrigin.Center);
bingMap.Children.Add(mapLayer);
```

If you do need have certain Pushpin functionality, another option is to use the PushPin template:

```
Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();
pushpin.Template = Application.Current.Resources["PushPinTemplate"]  
    as (ControlTemplate);
```

Then in your application resources XAML , you can define the template like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PushPinTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Width="32" Height="32">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
               <ImageBrush BitmapSource="YOUR IMAGE URL" /> 
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I added the above mentioned code using mapLayer for my code, but it does not show any pushpin on Map, any suggestions why it is not working?