# Changing the color of Bing Map pushpins

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, bing-maps, pushpin

How can I set the color of a pushpin programmatically through C# rather than XAML? How can I set font and size of a string associated with a pushpin through [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx) property? I'm not sure how to use [ContentStringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat.aspx) property to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pushpin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100,100,100,100));
```

Pushpin has inherited FontFamily and FontSize properties, they should have effect on the associated text.

```
pushpin.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
pushpin.FontSize = 20.0;
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you also know how I can change size of a pushpin? I tried changing Height and Width properties, but pushpin's size never changed. Also, how can I change pushpin's shape/icon into some other standard shape/icon provided by WPF? Or do I have to provide an image myself and make it my pushpin's icon?

Comment: You need to provide a `ControlTemplate` for the pushpin, it is in XAML - why do you prefer code over XAML? - fortunately there is already [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14559818/815938)